# Send bitmap from activity to class Android - without static methods

Tags: android

I would like send bitmap from activity to class, but without using static methods, or shared preference, any ideas?

Comment: Don't do that, store the image in some local folder and then send the path of the image to the class, to access the bitmap.

Comment: How send it ? Can you do some simple example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by do something like that: Hope it will help !

1. Write Method to encode your bitmap into string base64-

   ```
   // method for bitmap to base64
   public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
       Bitmap immage = image;
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       immage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
       byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
       String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

       Log.d("Image Log:", imageEncoded);
       return imageEncoded;
   }
   ```
2. Pass your bitmap inside this method like something in your preference:

   ```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefrence.edit();
   editor.putString("namePreferance", itemNAme);
   editor.putString("imagePreferance", encodeTobase64(yourbitmap));
   editor.commit();
   ```
3. And when you want to display your image just anywhere, convert it into a bitmap again using the decode method:

   ```
   // method for base64 to bitmap
   public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
       byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
       return BitmapFactory
               .decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
   }
   ```
4. Please pass your string inside this method and do what you want.

Comment: but I need send one object, and this is static

Comment: My dear friend, if it's static then use it directly in other class. By checking that object is NULL or not. Why to send or save in Sharedprefrence if you have static object.